# How to remove From and To filters from highstock?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Is there an option which removes **From** & **To** filters from Highstock? Check below image to check which part needs to be removed.

[image]

Range selector option

```
rangeSelector: {
    selected: 2,
    buttons: [ {
        type: "minute",
        count: 60,
        text: "1h"
    }, {
        type: 'day',
        count: 1,
        text: '1d'
    }, {
        type: 'day',
        count: 30,
        text: '1m'
    }, {
        type: 'day',
        count: 90,
        text: '3m'
    }, {
        type: 'day',
        count: 180,
        text: '6m'
    }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
    }]
}
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/tu44Lhx4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set inputEnabled to false ie:

```
rangeSelector: {
      inputEnabled:false,
    //...
}
```

please see here http://jsfiddle.net/zctctwcp/